# WPF: List boxes and virtualization

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualization

1. How do I know whether or not my list is being virtualized?
2. How do I make this snippet virtualized?

   ```
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Name="LogScroller">
       <r:NoInheritanceContentControl>
           <ListBox   Background="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveLog}" >
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Grid Background="Black">
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                               <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White">
                           <TextBlock >Date:</TextBlock>
                           <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=LogDate}"/>
                       </TextBlock>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White">
                           <TextBlock >Severity:</TextBlock>
                           <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Severity}"/>
                       </TextBlock>
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="LightGray" Text="{Binding Path=Message}"></TextBlock>
                       </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
               <ListBox.Template>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <StackPanel Background="Black" IsItemsHost="True" >
                       </StackPanel>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </ListBox.Template>
           </ListBox>
       </r:NoInheritanceContentControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
   ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code sample does not virtualize because you are forcing the use of a `StackPanel`.  You have to use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Comment: The link [bea.stollnitz blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/), doesn't seem to be relevant to the question any longer.  I suspect the information has moved.

Answer (score 7):

1. If you want to know for certain. Download [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) it has a 3d view that you can use to see every element that is rendered. (on and off screen) If your list box is not virtualised you will see all the list items marching off the page in a lovely 3d view.

It is an essential tool for the wpf developer as it has a couple of other really handy features as well

2. Get rid of that list box template that uses a stack panel. If all it is doing is making the background black, then just set the background black.

Comment: If I don't include the template then the scroll wheel on the mouse doesn't work. I did change it to a VirtualizingStackPanel.

Comment: I wish I could use Snoop, but I can't get it working against .NET 4.

Comment: throw a NotFairNoSnoopImplementedException() ):

Answer (score 2):

To know if it is virtualized you can simply add 10K dummy entries to the collection and see how fast the loading happens as well as how fast the vertical scroll works which will clearly tell a big difference.
I guess you need to change your `StackPanel` in the control template to `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Comment: I'll definitely try that, but without an answer to #1 I won't know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the MSDN forums, All databound listboxes are virtualized](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cd08eb55-650e-4f2e-83dc-b58672c467a4)

You can check what's going on in your app using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) - Mouse over your listbox (or one of the items) and look at the properties. One of them is `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` - it will be checked if the list is virtualized, and unchecked if not

Comment: Do you have nay other programs for testing? Unfortunately Snoop doesn't work with .NET 4.

Comment: Also, I read elsewhere that ListBoxes only virtualize by default. Once you start overriding stuff, you can lose the effect.

Comment: @jonathan allen (or do you write it @jonathan-allen because of the space?) Snoop now supports .NET 4.0. (Yes I know this is very old, but hey... some people may not know!)