# unselects the items on top when scrolling to bottom

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll, selection, unselect

I have a WPF `listbox`. The items are bound to the `listbox`.

When I select a few items at the top of the `listbox` and scroll down to the bottom of the `listbox` to select other items, the items that were earlier selected at the top are getting unselected.

I am finding this behavior with selection mode set to Extended as well as Multiple. Please advice.

Comment: did you   set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=True? that might do it...

Comment: Is it a result of virtualization?  Perhaps the items at the top are being unloaded as they scroll out of view.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143655/wpf-list-boxes-and-virtualization) for information about listbox virtualization.

Comment: I tried setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=True, but the behavior is still same. Sometimes, I find that a few of the selected items on the top remain selected, while others are unselected. It was a Virtualization problem. On setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll=False, the Virtualization is turned off and it works as expected. However, this can impact the performance a little. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off virtualization

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Team}" 
                       ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource NameDataStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - For anybody working with Silverlight who finds this answer, try using this:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```